# How to use variables in phpmailer message body

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm editing a form and I want to receive as mail when users fill it and send it. I received variables on mail before, such like: Name: $name. Now contact.php returns a blank page and I can't receive the form as mail.

I tried before that,

```
$body_message = 'Name: ' . $name . "\r\n"; 
$body_message .= 'E-mail: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n"; 
$body_message .= 'Message: ' . $message;
```

But it doesn't work. And that also,

```
$mail->Body = '<b>You have a reservation!</b>
Name: $name
Surname: $surname
Phone: $phone
Mail: $mail
Address: $address
Services: $check
';
```

Now my code:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$address= $_POST['address'];

if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {           
        return $check;
    }
}

$mail->Subject = 'Reservation';
$mail->Body    = '<b>You have a reservation!</b></br>'
.'Name: '.$name.'</br>'
.'Surname: '.$surname.'</br>'
.'Mail: '.$mail.'</br>'
.'Phone: '.$phone.'</br>'
.'Address: '.$address.'</br>'
.'Services: '.$check;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: return $check; is exiting your script.

Comment: There are two variable/instance make confusion `$mail->` and `$mail = $_POST` what is it?

Comment: did you check my answer. There is a syntax error in your code

Comment: Sorry @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd. I wrote wrong on here. Actually such like $umail.

Comment: You can see what is your mail contain before send it by `print_r($mail);exit();`, Place it before `if(!$mail->send())`. You can see if you make any mistake so you can fix it in easy way.

Comment: @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd. I tried on another page with echo, no problem. but I receive on mail such like: Name: $name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has 2 errors.

1.) You assign email address to $mail from form. Then access $mail instance which should be mistaken as PHPMailer instance.

```
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
....
....
$mail->Subject = 'Reservation';
$mail->Body    = '<b>You have a reservation!</b></br>'
....
....
```

2.) You are exiting from execution inside foreach

```
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {           
        return $check;
    }
}
```

**Fix**

```
$name    = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$email   = $_POST['mail'];
$phone   = $_POST['phone'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$services= array();

if (!empty($_POST['check_list']) && is_array($_POST['check_list'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {           
        $services[] = $check;
    }
}

$mail = new PHPMailer;
//other PHPMailer config options
....
....
$mail->Subject = 'Reservation';
$mail->Body    = '<b>You have a reservation!</b></br>'
.'Name: '.$name.'</br>'
.'Surname: '.$surname.'</br>'
.'Mail: '.$email.'</br>'
.'Phone: '.$phone.'</br>'
.'Address: '.$address.'</br>'
.'Services: '. implode(', ', $services);

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I was referring $check as array and your foreach also had the same variable. I have fixed it in the code. Now it is collecting check box values in $services variable.

Comment: Really thank you  @Pradeep Sanjaya :) It works. I m newbie in php and It was very instructive.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
```

means that `$mail` is a string with some email.

And this:

```
$mail->Subject
```

means that `$mail` is instance of some class.

Is it string or instance of some class? Can you tell?

And as already noticed - using `return` in your `foreach` causes your script or your function (whatever you have there) to either **stop script execution** or **end function execution**.